# Estoy creando excepciones en Java pero al ingresar un if dentro de otro if no me funciona la excepcion 5

Tags: java

La excepcion 5 no me da el resultado esperado, todas las demás funcionan perfectamente.Como puedo solucionar el problema ?

````
            if(txtIdentificacion.getText().isEmpty() || txtNombre.getText().isEmpty()){
                throw new Excepciones(1);
            }else if(cmbDeporte.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Futblista")){
                if(cmbPie.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-") || cmbPosicion.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-")){
                    throw new Excepciones(5);
                }
                
            }else{
                insertarAtleta();
            }
        }catch(Excepciones e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(), "Errores de entrada", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error, ingreso letra en un campo numerico" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), "Errores de entrada", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }```
````

Comment: A que se refiere con que no da el resultado?? puede ser de que nunca entre al if

Comment: No aplica la Excepcion, simplemente no hace nada. Quiero que el cliente elija el tipo de deporte, en este caso si elije futbolista se prenden 2 casillas mas de pie dominante y posición. Lo que quiero es que estas 2 casillas nuevas no se puedan ingresar sin haber seleccionado la opción.

Comment: Pues la cadena de comparación no dice Futbolista, dice Futblista, si envia Futbolista estas nunca serán iguales por ende no ingresan al else if y me imagino que se ejecutara insertarAlerta();

Comment: Si amigo, lo escribí mal por acá pero ya lo solucione. Gracias